# Change language to arabic without changing window/GUI alignment

Tags: unity, gui, window, language-support

I recently changed my language to arabic but I found that the GUI is flipped horizontally which is not so nice and kinda nauseous. How do I make the GUI left-aligned with arabic language still present? Thanks!

[image: Nemo]
[image: Google Chrome]

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: ... and which application?

Comment: @younes ubuntu version? 14.04

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson All applications is inverted

Comment: Could reproduce it. Hmm.. Interesting. ;) Some googling made me believe this is not a bug, but a feature. Suppose it's unlikely that there is an easy workaround available to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arabic is an RTL (right-to-left) language, you cannot. The UI elements are changed position, because that is how they are supposed to be displayed, in order to fit the right-to-left orientation of the language.

Another [answer on UX StackExchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/55129) has some more info on why it is necessary.